# Is it Overfitting if validation metric is improving but training metric is extremely high?

Tags: overfitting

If Accuracy or AUC for 4 different values of a tuning parameter in a model,

- ntrees in randomforest from 500 , 1000 , 1500 , 2000
- over Training Data is 0.7 , 0.8 , 0.9 , 1.0
- over Test / Validation Data is 0.6 , 0.62 , 0.64 , 0.66

Has overfitting occured ? (Essentially no elbow / minima / maxima being formed when plotting the metric on the validation set is what makes me doubt this)

Articles online [like this one](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/learning-curves-machine-learning/) seem to always have diagrams with a L curve / elbow.

- Is the pattern just "IDEAL" case and real world data rarely follows the pattern?
- Are there any "regular culprits" which may cause such behaviour?

  2. Does sparseness of data matter in this context ? [ Positive cases < 7% of Total ]

Comment: This needs more details. Based on the results, I would say almost certainly.

Comment: What does the series of values mean--is this over time/iterations? btw, the goal is typically not to eliminate all overfitting but, rather, to attain the highest generalization performance possible. This requires finding the right balance between over- and underfitting, which is often done by maximizing performance on the validation set.

Comment: For the case consider no of trees in a random forest model being increased from 500 , 1000 ,1500, 2000... however i am looking at a more general case where it could have occurred for any tuning parameter for any model.